# How to display the number of frames per second in mplayer

Tags: mplayer, command-line

Is there a command (either a command line option, or a navigation command) to display the number of frames per second of the playing movie?

I am testing to see if my computer is slow (ie running at less than 30 fps) or if the video was sampled poorly.

Note: I did try to 'google it', but googling for 'mplayer' and 'fps' returns how to set the desired number of frames per second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds as if you are interested in benchmarking, try the `-benchmark` option.

From the [ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/mplayer.1.html)

> -benchmark
>                 Prints some statistics on CPU usage and dropped  frames  at  the
>                 end  of playback.  Use in combination with -nosound and -vo null
>                 for benchmarking only the video codec.
>                 NOTE: With this option MPlayer will also ignore  frame  duration
>                 when playing only video (you can think of that as infinite fps).

```
mplayer -benchmark -nosound -vo null your_file
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! Yet it doesn't at all do what I want. Where is the information displayed? I was hoping it would be displayed either on the movie, or in the console, but it doesn't appear anywhere. Also, the fps is indicated in the console, but I believe that's the intended frame rate, not the actual rate

Comment: It will print stats at the end of the playback. What is it you are trying to benchmark exactly ? If you start mplayer from the command line I believe it displays FPS in the terminal.

Comment: My video is choppy and I want to know if it's due to low performance or low video quality. The FPS is displayed in the terminal, but it is exactly 24.000 fps. I am assuming this is the intended frame rate. Surely at some point the frame rate will drop below 24.000

Comment: Is the playback choppy with only a single file, or all files ? What video card do you have ? I am not sure how benchmarks are going to help you debug your problem.

Comment: It's mostly choppy with 720p files, but I think it has to do with the fact that they are 25 fps

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the open source drivers, you can use `GALLIUM_HUD=fps <program>` to display the FPS. I personally use mpv rather than mplayer, so for me that would be `GALLIUM_HUD=fps mpv <video>`